# Как получить данные из формы без Jquery

Tags: javascript

Вешаю обрабочик на форму:

```
   onsubmit: function() {

    var url = 'http://test.ru/?'name='+name+'&phone='+phone;
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onload = function (){
        location.href('thanks.html');
    }
    request.send();
    return false;
}
```

Но как получить переменные name и phone из именно этой формы?нужны именно переменные т.к могут добавляться любые параметры которые не передаются из формы

Answer (score 1):

Как то так можно по идее:

```
onsubmit: function() {
    var name = this.name.value;
    var phone = this.name.phone;
    var url = 'http://test.ru/?'name='+name+'&phone='+phone;
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onload = function (){
        location.href('thanks.html');
    }
    request.send();
    return false;
}
```

Но конечно будет надежнее приклепать к полям ввода id и получать value c их помощью